# SQL Query to pull data for current month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wanting to do a count of the dispositions and only count the ones in the current month, here is the code I have:

```
SELECT        Disposition, COUNT(Disposition) AS Count, Date
FROM            CSLogs.dbo.Logs
GROUP BY Disposition, Date
HAVING        (DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(month, Date)) AND (DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(year, Date))
```

But the results I get are:

```
Disposition Count   Date
LOC         1       2012-12-10
Save        3       2012-12-11
LOC         1       2012-12-12
Sale        1       2012-12-12
Save        3       2012-12-12
```

As you can see I have duplicates, but I am not looking for that, I am looking for example, LOC to say under count is 2 and not have the date column showing.

Hopefully I have given enough info and thanks in advance!

Comment: why not in the `where` clause

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfMonth datetime, @LastDayOfMonth datetime
--You can create scalar functions dbo.GetFirstDayOfMonth and dbo.GetLastDayOfMonth
-- try this from December 2012
SELECT @FirstDayOfMonth = '20121201', @LastDayOfMonth = '20121231'

    SELECT Disposition, COUNT(Disposition) AS Count
    FROM CSLogs.dbo.Logs
    WHERE Date BETWEEN @FirstDayOfMonth AND @LastDayOfMonth
    GROUP BY Disposition
```

This is more efficient, the engine can use index on Date if exists.

**EDIT**

I want to clarify this trick. This is helper functions which always needed in date-oriented DB.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfMonth') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfMonth
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfMonth(@DATE DATE)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATETIME)
END
GO

IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfNextMonth') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfNextMonth
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfNextMonth(@DATE DATE)
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATETIME)
END
GO
```

Now you can try this:

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfMonth datetime, @FirstDayOfNextMonth datetime
SELECT @FirstDayOfMonth = dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfMonth(GETDATE()), @FirstDayOfNextMonth = dbo.ufn_FisrtDayOfNextMonth(GETDATE())

    SELECT Disposition, COUNT(Disposition) AS Count
    FROM CSLogs.dbo.Logs
    WHERE Date >= @FirstDayOfMonth
      AND Date < @FirstDayOfNextMonth
    GROUP BY Disposition
```

Comment: when I put all of that into SQL query to make sure that the query runs like expected, I did not get any results.

Comment: Are you set `@FirstDayOfMonth` and `@LastDayOfMonth` to appropriate values?

Comment: I am going to go with no.  Not sure what scalar function is.

Comment: That will work, but looks like I would have to manually type in the days of the month when the next month comes around.  Correct?

Comment: Not. You can create functions that will return first and last dates of month for given date, i.e. for `GATEDATE()`.

Comment: @ncurran217 are you using mysql?

Comment: then leave it to SQL Server: `SELECT DATEPART(day,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))`

Comment: @luchosrock I am not sure where I would be putting that.  Is that in addition to Hamlet's code above?

Comment: I meant you should `set @LastDayOfMonth = SELECT DATEPART(day,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))` before the SELECT statement

Comment: I was all wrong, let me explain it better 
 `SET @LastDayOfMonth = SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))`

Comment: Ok so what about the @FirstDayOfMonth, also, when I put that in before my select statement, it gives a syntax error at the Select before DATEADD.

Comment: `SET @FirstDayOfMonth = SELECT DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE())`

Comment: Awesome!  That worked once I took the SELECT out of your statement!  Thanks to both of you!!!