# How to get monthly total in SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have

The following query which gets the total for the day:

```
SELECT *
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

The following query which gets the total for the week:

```
SELECT * , DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Date)
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE Date >= cast(dateadd(day,1-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate()) as date)
```

How can I write a query which will give me the total for the month, given it starts from the first to the end of the month only?

The table looks like the following and it will continue to add itself for each day:

[image]

So tomorrow it will be entry #4 and date will be 2014-04-11 and so on and so on...

I will need to query which will be called in my Datasets for my SSRS report to create a bar chart.

The original query which the image is displayed for is:

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase.dbo.TABLE
Select getdate(),
Count([Draw Date]),
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radClinicalInHouseLab]) AS [IN HOUSE],
(Select Count([Column 0]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radRadOrders]) AS [RAD EMR ORDERS],
(Select Count([Value]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radEMROrders]) AS [EMR ORDERS],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radAccessLabOrders]) AS [ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radAPSurgical]) AS [AP SURGICAL],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radClinicalRefLab]) AS [REF LAB],
(Select Count([Column 0]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radRadResults]) AS [RAD RESULTED],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radLabResults]) AS [LAB_RESULT], --added 4/4
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radResultedLabOrders]) AS [RESULTED LAB], --4/4
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radAPCytology]) AS [AP CYTOLOGY MOLECULAR],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radAutoAccessRadOrders]) AS [RAD ACCESSIONED],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radPendingLabResults]) AS [PENDING LAB], --4/4
((Select Count([Value]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radEMROrders]) - (Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radAccessLabOrders])) AS [PENDING FOR PROCESSING],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radChemInHouse]) AS [CHEMISTRY],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radBloodBank]) AS [BLOOD BANK],
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radHemotology]),
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radMicrobiology]),
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radSerology]),
(Select Count([Draw Date]) from mydatabase.dbo.[radUrinalysis])
FROM mydatabase.dbo.[radAPDERM]
```

For some reason I can't get the following query to display the same Date format:

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),110) AS Date_Value,
'First Day of Current Month' AS Date_Type
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),110) ,
'Last Day of Current Month'
```

which displays:

[image]

Result table:

[image]

```
APDERM  IN HOUSE    RAD EMR ORDERS  EMR ORDERS  ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS  AP SURGICAL REF LAB RAD RESULTED    LAB_RESULT  RESULTED LAB    AP CYTOLOGY MOLECULAR   RAD ACCESSIONED PENDING LAB PENDING FOR PROCESSING  CHEMISTRY   BLOOD BANK  HEMOTOLOGY  MICROBIOLOGY    SEROLOGY    URINALYSIS
31  5122    35404   271265  7165    106 790 24736   61807   0   311 1122    2987    264100  4193    42  971 100 67  389
```

With query:

[image]

Comment: What's your definition of `total`

Comment: The query should check the DATE column and compare it to the current month to make sure it falls under the current month and add up each column for the month.

Comment: `The original query which the image is displayed for is:` UPDATE query?

Comment: So, currently all three entry falls under the current month, so it will add `23+0+2` for `APDERM` and give me `25`

Comment: There is two part to it. I only included the first part but it can be `INSERT INTO` as well.

Comment: I updated my question so it's not INSERT INTO instead of UPDATE. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATE
SET @DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT SUM(APDERM) as total
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE) -- the first day of current month
  AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE) -- the first day of next month
```

You can refer to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861736/sql-query-to-pull-data-for-current-month/13861792#13861792) to get helper `UDF`s.

Comment: I am getting `31` which isn't what the total is. It should be `25`. I don't want to know the number of days :/ The above data is actual data so I should get 25 and not 31, right?

Comment: @SiKni8 can you show the data(if it is possible) on which the query return wrong result.

Comment: `DECLARE @DATE DATE
SET @DATE = GETDATE()
SELECT SUM(APDERM) as APDERM, SUM([IN HOUSE]) as [IN HOUSE]
FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[RADRESULTSTOTALS]
WHERE [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, @DATE) as DATE) -- the first day of current month
  AND [Date] < CAST(DATEADD(d, - DATEPART(d, @DATE) + 1, DATEADD(m, 1, @DATE)) as DATE) -- the first day of next month`

Comment: for `APDERM` it shows 31 while for `IN HOUSE` it shows 5122. The first one is wrong while the second one if you sum it up is correct.

Comment: @SiKni8 I want to see the **data** on which this query is run.

Comment: How would you like me to show you? You mean the table? If so the image is above which is outputting from my query right now.

Comment: The data is being pulled from an SSIS package so even if I add the code will it help you?

Comment: Can you show the result of query `SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[RADRESULTSTOTALS]` if it is not so big?

Comment: It's a big table but I added it at the bottom of the question for you to check :) Thanks. I also added the table result from your query. Some of the number matches while some doesn't match. confuses me...

Comment: The result has only three rows? And you claim that the sum of that three values returned is 31? Then your sql server baggy.

Comment: I see your query result also has so many columns than mentioned in comment. Add the exact query to the post too.

Comment: If you notice the only column that matches are, IN HOUSE, ACCESSIONED LAB ORDERS and REF LAB and everything else the numbers are way off :/

Comment: I added the columns but it's too wide to fit in an image but I tried my best to put it in my question. Not sure if it will help...

Comment: Ohm.., not result, just **query**.

Comment: ACTUALLY...NEVERMIND... SILLY ME!!! I forgot to update the query and the number changed. It NOW makes sense... HAHAHAHA. I feel dumb!

Comment: Congratulations... :)

Comment: It's working now. THANK YOU. Will the query automatically take care of the next month as well? So when its 05 for month it will only add starting from 5-1-2014 and so on and so on...?

Comment: You can easy understand that by analyzing the WHERE clause :)

Comment: Actually you are right. It's not hardcoded date so it will. Answered my own question. Thanks :)